# Deallocing and reallocing MKMapView

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, dealloc, memory-management

I have a Navigation View Controller and many of it's child VCs have maps. And if I go down navigating through n views, I'll have always n-1 maps allocated in memory.
My idea is to deallocate a map every time the view controller disappears, and reallocate it when it appears again.

However, they were laid out using a storyboard, and their frames change depending on the devices orientation because I'm using constraints. This way, when the VC is loaded for the first time, it appears as on the storyboard. But when I deallocate it and I have to reallocate, I don't know how to set the frame correctly, or how to add the constraints properly.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: I think when you push the controller into navigation controller they will get the frame either from nib or programatically and when you pop them from navigation controller they get deallocate so whats the issue ///

Comment: When I push the first VC, it opens OK. Then when I push the second, I am deallocating the map in the first. When I pop the second, I need to reallocate the map in the first. That's because the first VC was never popped, therefore never deallocated.

Comment: Yes its best way i guess you can set the view to nil before pushing and later when you pop in viewWillAppear you can allocate the Map View

Comment: I am making some tests, and it appears to help, but I'm not sure yet if this is the best way. A problem that arrises from this method is that any input changed by the user will be reset when I pop back to the VC. Since not all VCs have data like that, I believe that it can work in some of them, at least.

Comment: you can save data into coredata if user input or update and later you can send to server

Comment: I'm not using CoreData though.

Comment: @Retro I tried setting `self.view` to `nil`, and it works on iOS 6, but on 7, when I pop one view controller, it crashes with the following messages: http://pastebin.com/pXDQBabV

Comment: no, not the self.view just your map view object

Comment: I did set only the map to `nil` before, but when I pop, the map reference I had is lost. I cannot control the map anymore (which is still there, btw). In other words, setting the map to `nil` is not deallocing it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to read up on creating constraints programmatically. You can use the debugger to log the constraints on your map view before deallocating it, and then write code to recreate those constraints when you add the map back in.

Comment: Sure, that's another option I had thought. But I wanted to know if there were better options to that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to read the property like user location and other attribute and save it before setting to nil and when you comes back check this object in viewWillAppear like

```
if(!mapView) {
  allocate here and set the saved values
}
```